# Prove that you cannot solve clearly for y in $ (x^2+y^2)^2+3x^2y-y^3=0 $

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I am supposed to decide whether or not you can solve the equation clearly $ f(x, y)=(x^2+y^2)^2+3x^2y-y^3=0 $ for $x$ or $y$, with $x, y, \in U$,    $(0, 0) \in U$ and $U$ open. When looking at the set of $x$ and $y$ solving that equation it is pretty clear that such a $U$ does not exist.

It is pretty easy to show that you can not solve for $x$, as for any circle around $(0, 0)$, if $(x, y)$ is in that circle, $(-x, y)$ is in the circle as well. ($f$ is symmetric, so $0=f(x, y=f(-x, y)$)

Now I would like to show that you can also not solve for $y$. Or in other words for any circle with an arbitrarily small radius if $(x, y)$ is in that circle I need to find $c$, such that $0=f(x, y)=f(x, cy)$, but I could not manage to find such a $c$.

[image: solution set of equation]

Can anyone provide me with that $c$ or is there a better approach?

Comment: I am not sure I am following, we can solve for four $x$ values, for example $$x\to \frac{\sqrt{-2 y^2-\sqrt{16 y+9} y-3 y}}{\sqrt{2}}$$ We can also do the same for $y$, but that is much uglier. Am  I missing something you are saying?

Comment: As was observed in the comment by  @Moo , $f(x,y)=0$ is a quadratic equation of $x^2,$ so you can solve for $x^2,$ and then for $x.$

Comment: What I am saying is that you cannot represent the solution as the graph of a function upon $x$ or $y$. as in the implicit function theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: Geometrically one can see that any small circle centered at the origin intersects the graph in 6 points. Of course to explicitly calculate those points, say as a function of the radius $r$ of the small circle, would be quite involved. But in theory these points exist.

Comment: By applying the radial coordinates the equation takes the form $r=4\sin t\sin(t+{\pi\over 3})\sin(t-{\pi\over 3}),$ so the graph is indeed invariant under rotation by $2\pi/3.$ Hence for small fixed $x$ or small fixed $y$ there are $3$ solutions.

Comment: @coffeemath I was unprecise. The OP wants to use implicit function theorem in an open set containing $0.$ So if we get closer  and closer to $0$ the problem occurs.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  Your polar equation does near the origin give several points on the curve. What I wonder about is whether for any small circle there are two point on that circle which are also on the clover, *and* have the same x-value.

Answer (score 3):

COMMENT.-First at all, a circle in a open neighbourhood  of $(0,0)$ don't need its center be $(0,0)$, even $(0,0)$ could be out of the circle.

Whatever be the fixed value of $x$ or $y$, the resulting equation in one variable being of $4$-degree has four roots (real and/or imaginary ones).

Besides the equation
being $x^4+(2y^2+3y)x^2+(y^4-y^3)=0$, we easily have
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-(2y^2+3y)^2\pm\sqrt{16y^3+9y^2}}{2}}=g(y)\tag 1$$ We can verify that always $-(2y^2+3y)^2+\sqrt{16y^3+9y^2}\le-3$  (*this negative maximum is reached for $y=-0.5$*) which implies that the four functions $x=h(y)$ we can get with the $\pm$ signes from the initial one are not real functions.

For the possibility $y=h(x)$ we cannot do easily as for $x=g(y)$. Anyway I agree with the viewpoint of the O.P. on the impossibility but this feeling is not a proof.